# Angular's Control Value Accessor no binding value?

Tags: angular

I'm having big troubles with angular form value accessor.

Look first parent component and nested child component

test is ony var like :

```
test: any = '';
```

Right now child component : '@angular/forms';

```
@Component({ 
....
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => Test),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class Teste implements ControlValueAccessor {



}
```

This is should be work but when i console.log my 'test' variable i got undefined or empty string..

Where is error ?

Comment: Your stackblitz working fine

Comment: Stackblitz is example according to which I worked... But my code no work

Comment: Here is my demonstration please check : https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-picker-controlvalue-accessor?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Chellappanவ check my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need call to `dateValueChanged` when the `dateTime`change. You can do it "split" `[(ngModel)]`in `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`

```
 <input type="text" [ngModel]="dateTime" 
                (ngModelChange)="dateTime=$event;dateValueChanged()" 
  bsDatepicker>
```

**Update** if we want to improve the custom component passing a label or a placeHolder we can make it using @Input (or attribute)

Using input it's only, in the component

```
@Input()placeHolder;
@Input()label;

{{label}}
<input type="text" [attr.placeholder]="placeholder" [ngModel]="dateTime" 
                    (ngModelChange)="dateTime=$event;dateValueChanged()" 
      bsDatepicker>
```

Using Attribute it's only in constructor use

```
constructor(@Optional() @Attribute('placeholder') private placeholder:string,
            @Optional() @Attribute('label') private label:string
            ){}
```

In general, if we are not planning change the "label" nor the "placeholder" it's would prefer the use of this second approach.

**Update2** well, if we want that our custom formControl received a "string" and return a "string" we need use the function writeValue and dateValueChanged

writevalue receive the value of the formControl, we received a string, but we need that dateTime was a Date

We can use momment or a function like:

```
  //received a "string", need this.dateTime was a Date object
  writeValue(input: string) {
    const parts=input?input.match(/\d+/g):null
    if (parts && parts.length==3)
      this.dateTime=new Date(+parts[2],(+parts[1])-1,+parts[0])
    else
      this.dateTime=new Date();
  }
```

In dateValueChanged we can make

```
  dateValueChanged(): void {
    const data=("00"+this.dateTime.getDate()).slice(-2)+"-"+
    ('00'+(this.dateTime.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+
        this.dateTime.getFullYear()
    this.onChange(data);
  }
```

NOTE: It's only a "example", I don't know if bsDatePicker has a "parse" method or a way to localize

Comment: Okay I will try it , but can you explain me why ? It is important for me to understand why that?

Comment: The "ControlValue Accesor" need call to `this.onChange` function when a change happens -the "magic" is the instruction:`registerOnChange(fn: any): void {this.onChange = fn;}` . This it's neccesary make it "manually" (in a very simple custom control it's possible make it using `[(ngModel)]' . Your code only change the inner variable `dateTime` but not call the function

Comment: Jasper, I forked your stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-picker-controlvalue-accessor-qtjxfr?file=app%2Fcalendar%2Fcalendar.component.ts

Comment: Oh i have error because i don't set name atribute.... Thanks

Comment: One more question, how to add dynamic placeholder and label for datepicker if i set to few places? Btw vote up for you

Comment: Example in parent component i want to set different placeholder ? How to do it ? and how to format date in child component

Comment: Also one more question, I am maybe boring but i am very interested about this. Do need important to date be @Input or can be basic variable inside child component

Comment: Yes, the "dateTime" should be a simple variable. NOTE: I updated the answer to add "label" and "placeholder"

Comment: Hmm how to bind in parent component placeholder? Thanks.

Comment: and friend how to format this date ? Format output no here in input then selected value right now is: Fri May 28 2021 14:25:21 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) but i want to example 10-10-2021

Comment: Jasper, the control get and feed an javascript object Date, you can use the datepipe from angular:https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe to "format" the value, but remember that the variable will be always a Date object of javascript, e.g. `{{ dateObj | date:'dd-MM-yyyy }}`

Comment: I know this pipe for format date but I want to to format the date within the child components and return the already formed date to the parent components

Comment: i Will try inside function writeValue with moment(date).format('dd-MM-YYYY) but no work...

Comment: I want to format date in child and send to parent already formated date. [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }  is only on input format

Comment: @Jasper, sorry the delay, I update the answer. The "key" is take account that the function "writeValue" is executed one time -received the value of the control-. The function onChange makes possible we send a string based in the value of DateTime